# avconv pipe to v4l2loopback device

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv, v4l

I use v4l2loopback module to create two video device. My intention is to pipe output from primary video device to these two virtual devices.
I can do that using ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 5 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video3`

But i want to do that using avconv. I try'it as output v4l2 format and video4linux2 but nothing work.
I know avconv is very similar to ffmpeg, but do not know how to accomplish what I want using avconv.